# back button in php to go all previous pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to code a project, fox example my project has 10 pages, and I have back and forward button in every page. SO when i code using    `javascript:history.go(-1)` or

```
$url = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

and `echo` the `$url`, it just takes me to previous page, and when i click back button on the previous page I am back to current or latest page, I want to step by step back while clicking back button in every page from 10, 9, 8, 7 .... 1. Hope my point is clear. I will be glad for any suggestions. :-) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use these instead.

```
window.history.back();
window.history.forward();
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you already called javascript:history.go(-1) or called the $url, therefore the page will be different when calling it again

Try something like storing it in an array or using the following methods 
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_history.asp

```
window.history.back();
```

Comment: Thanks Rbx, but window.history.back(); wont go beyond last page. Storing in array and recalling may be the option I feel.

Answer (score 0):

One thought that might be of interest would be to utilise `sessionStorage` to maintain a history of pages visited - then, when trying to invoke the previous page functionality, you could do a lookup into the sessionStorage item to find either the page or the index depending upon how you implement it to begin with.

For instance, you could do:

```
if( !sessionStorage.getItem('history') ) sessionStorage.setItem('history',1);
else sessionStorage.setItem('history', parseInt( sessionStorage.getItem('history') ) + 1 );
```

or store a json object

```
sessionStorage.setItem('history',JSON.stringify({page:document.location.href)); /* this would require tweaking! */
```

This would give you an easier method than cookies to store a history which can be used when calling `window.history.go( )` etc